# How to access model method based on api auth in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have user cars having many to many relation between users and cars. I am using passport and everthing is working properly (Sign-in, Sign-up etc) In my I have a method like below in Users Model

```
public function cars()
    { 
        return $this->belongsToMany(Car::class, 'users_cars', 'user_id', 'car_id');
    }
```

I also have API auth routes which is working fine

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');

    Route::group([
      'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
        Route::get('car-list','CarController@carList');
    });
});
```

And in CarController I am trying to get user cars based on auth login `user_id` as like below

```
public function carList(){
    $User = new User();
    return new CarResource($User->cars());
}
```

I am also using API resource for API's

```
use App\Http\Resources\Car as CarResource;
```

But it does not working so can someone kindly guide me how to fix the issue. I would appreciate, thank you so much.

Comment: What is CarResource?

Comment: @KyleWardle this is API Resource for API's

Comment: I believe you should use `return new CarResource($User->cars);` or `return new CarResource($User->cars()->get());`

Comment: @cbaconnier I tried both of but does not working for me

Comment: As @KyleWardle said, your `$User` **can't** have car based on your code. You need to get an User that already have at least one to prove it works.

Answer (score 1):

In the `CarController` you are instantiating a new `User` object. They are never going to have any cars. If you want to get all the cars that the user who is logged in, you will need to do something like the following:

```
public function carList(){
    $User = User::with('cars')->findOrFail(Auth::id());
    return new CarResource($User->cars);
}
```

Comment: When you say not working, is it giving an error? Returning no data?

Comment: It is working now but return an blank array `datat:[]`

Comment: Perfect it is working when I add static `user_id` like this `findOrFail(3);`

Comment: I found a way which is working `findOrFail(request()->user()->id);` and is this is best practice ?